# Fetching rows take longer than running query

Tags: java, oracle, fetch

My SQL query takes just 1 minute to execute but fetching total rows which can go upto 1 million takes almost 11 minutes.

Following is the Pseudo code :

```
stmt.setFetchSize(5000);

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()){
  //Do some task
}
```

I have tried changing fetch size from 100 to 80000 but nothing helps, it still takes more than 10 minutes.
If i remove while loop and simply execute the query then whole process takes just few minutes which implies that query is executing fast.

Any suggestions on how to improve the time for fetching of rows?

Comment: What is "//Do some task"? If it's something the DBMS itself can do efficiently, you're wasting your time bringing the data locally.

Comment: No it can't be done in DBMS, after data is fetched. We need to run lots of analytics on data which is in java layer.

Comment: Try conn.setAutoCommitMode(false);

Comment: @JaydeepRajput : How will this help ?

Comment: Auto-commit mode indicates to the database whether to issue an automatic COMMIT operation after every SQL operation. Being in auto-commit mode can be expensive in terms of time and processing effort

Comment: But this is a single transaction and a read only operation. COmmit should never come into picture.

Comment: Which query you are executing /? Can you mention it in your question ?

Comment: even though the while loop is completely empty, it takes 11 minutes ?

Comment: @hunter : True. Its just the next call which consumes all the time.

Comment: @Lokesh, anyway setFetchSize is just a hint for the JDBC driver and driver implementation has freedom to ignore it. since you are using Oracle (JDBC) you can try to use oracle specific API.this is just a trial and error test. remove the setFetchSize call . cast you statement to OracleStatement, and then call setRowPrefetch(5000) just before call the execute.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing  you can do at the app level is to:
 1. return less data (either by less rows or less columns) 
 2. increase array fetch size (thereby reducing network round trips via SQL*Net which is a "chatty protocol") 
 3. have a faster network (thereby reducing the time spent in the network round trips) 
 4. co-locating app server on same local area network with the DB (essentially a faster network).